# mapr stream api causing java fatal crash

Tags: stream, kafka-producer-api, mapr

platform : MapR 5.2 on sandbox
JAVA FATAL CRASH WHEN trying to write using producer

```
{  public static void configureProducer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("acks", "all");
    props.put("retries", 0);
    props.put("batch.size", 16384);
    props.put("linger.ms", 1);
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
    //props.put("partitioner.class", "com.activetik.market.kafka.custompartitioner.KafkaUserCustomPatitioner");
    producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
}

producer.send(record, new Callback() {
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
                PROCESSED.incrementAndGet();
            }
        });}
```

Exception

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_UNCAUGHT_CXX_EXCEPTION (0xe06d7363) at pc=0x00007ff95b4d9e08, 
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x69e08]
```